# Adding item to Thread::Queue in Perl gives me error "lock can be used only on shared values"

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue

I have a process which accesses a `$taskobj` which has a `Thread::Queue` queue and starts child threads. I have no issue in accessing the `$taskobj` before forking, but after forking in the child thread I tried to call `enqueue` on the queue object in `$taskobj`. It is giving me an error

> lock can only be used on shared values

**Task.pm**

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self;
  $self->{ID} = 0;
  my $taskqueue = Thread::Queue->new();
  $self->{TaskQ} = $taskqueue;
}

sub queueing {
  my $self = shift;
  my $id = $self->{ID};
  my $que = $self->{TaskQ};

  $que->enqueue($id); # getting error here after forking

  $self->{ID} += 1;
  return $id;
}
```

**Parent process**

```
sub initializethreads {
  my taskobj = new task();
  taskobj -> queueing();
}
```

**child process**

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $paralellprocess = new Parallel::ForkManager();

sub initializethreads {
  my taskobj = new task();
  $taskobj->queueing; # error
}
```

Comment: That Perl code is a long way from even compiling. Please would you show the actual code you're having trouble with?

Comment: It looks like you are confusing threads with fork. They can live with each other, but they are not compatible or the same.

Comment: The program wont compile.The actual program code is around 100+ lines.I have just given the problem part.

Comment: You are asking a question about a program that raised errors when you called `$que->enqueue($id)`. That program must have compiled for you to be able to run it and get that result. 100 lines isn't very much - please post the code you are havihg trouble with: we can't tell anything from a minimal part of the program that you have made up instead of copying.

Comment: I have done my best to make sense of your code. I really shouldn't have to do that. Do you really have two identical subroutines `initializethreads` in your main and child processes?

Comment: yes.I have two same subroutines to create threads at parentlevel and child level.I want the threads at parent lvel to be independent of the child level threads.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have become *very* confused. `fork` and `threads` are different things, and you have *both* `Thread::Queue` and `Parallel::ForkManager` in place. It is a very bad idea to use both unless you absolutely *have* to.

To work correctly, the `Thread::Queue` object must be *shared* across all the threads that need to acccess the queue. You don't show what you are *doing* with `Parallel::ForkManager`, but if you fork a secondary process and then `$que` will no longer be shared between main and the forked process, unless you make a special arrangement to *make* it shared using `forks::shared`.

Since `Parallel::ForkManager` is already using `threads::shared` to share the queue between threads you would end up with a mess of a program that is highly unlikely to work.

Because you need your data to be shared I recommend you stick with `threads` and `Thread::Queue` and forget about forking. If you prefer you could try doing it with `fork`, but *not* both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Borodin for your answers